# Using jquery in crossrider background contextMenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, crossrider

I've this following piece of code in background.js.

```
appAPI.contextMenu.add("key2", "Add", function (data) {
var key=0;
alert('hi'+data.selectedText);
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == data.selectedText;
        }).closest("tr");

alert("1");         
alert(tableRow+'sds');
        if(tableRow===null)
        {
            alert("Please select proper text so that course can be selected, this would title or coursenumber");
            return;

        }   
        var title=tableRow.find('td').eq(7).text();
        var days=tableRow.find('td').eq(8).text();
        var time=tableRow.find('td').eq(9).text();
        timeSplit=time.split('-');
        var startTime,endTime;
        startTime=getTime(timeSplit[0]);           
        endTime=getTime(timeSplit[1]);
        var loc=tableRow.find('td').eq(10).text();
        var instructor=tableRow.find('td').eq(12).text();

        key=key+1;
        courseData=[{'id':key,'title':title,'days':days,'startTime':startTime,'endTime':endTime,'loc':loc,'instructor':instructor}];

        var dbData=appAPI.db.get('course_Data');
        if(dbData===null)
        {
            dbData=courseData;
        }
        else
        {
          dbData.push({'id':key,'title':title,'days':days,'startTime':startTime,'endTime':endTime,'loc':loc,'instructor':instructor});
        }
        alert(dbData[key-1]['title']);
        appAPI.db.set('course_Data',dbData);


  }, ["all"]);
```

The same code when I keep in extension.js works perfectly fine with appAPI selectedText method, but in background the jquery part seems to not work.
I say that because I'm not able to reach the alert('1') statement with the jquery code before it to filter out table tows based upon the selected value.

Answer (score 4):

The Crossrider background scope does not support jQuery at this time which is why your code isn't working in background.js.

You can use the regular DOM objects (e.g. window, document) to achieve the same result in the background scope.

Comment: I hope they add support, it would be wasteful to not have.

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake regarding access to the table from the background scope. By architecture, the background scope cannot access the page DOM and hence even jQuery and the window/document objects wouldn't be able to access the table as they reference the DOM of the background scope.  However, you can achieve your goal by [sending a message](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message) from the background scope to the relevant page tab, and then in the extension's page code (extension.js) run your code to work with the table. Let me know if you need any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't see any `alert('1')` the script must either terminate abruptly before it or loop indefinitely. I don't think those jQuery calls can possibly loop indefinitely, so I guess it crashes because your `data` object doesn't contain any `selectedText` field. Is that possible?